# WCF vs IHttpHandler

Tags: wcf, ihttphandler

Is there something in WCF that can simulate http streaming like  IHttpHandler can do?

I want a way to constantly write bytes to my http response non stop to my client until there is nothing left to write using WCF and was just wondering if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: There is a streaming transfer mode for WCF - is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

WCF allows streaming by setting the TransferMode property of the binding to 'Streamed', 'StreamedRequest' or 'StreamedResponse', depending on your needs.

Check the following MSDN articles for more information on it:

- [Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)
- [Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Comment: Yes but i need to provide a streaming service where non .Net apps can access the service using Http (all languages/ platforms seem to at least support http) so was wondering if WCF could provide this.